# jStepper and getting maxValue from attribute of input

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have textbox

`<input id="mytextbox" class="skill" type="text" rel="10">`

and I use jquery plugin jStepper. How long I use nonstant limit values, all work perfectly:

```
$('.skill').jStepper({ minValue: 0, maxValue: 20 });
```

Problem is when I want to get maxValue from parameter "rel":

`$('.skill').jStepper({minValue: 0, maxValue: parseInt($(this).attr('rel'))});`

Then max limit don't work. What can I do to it work? Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `parseInt($(this).attr('rel'))` is returning the right result?  Try using `console.log` to output the value that you are using (and possibly its class).

Answer (score 0):

So nice to see that my plugin is used! :D

If you know that you have only one field to attach jStepper to, then you can do the following:

```
var jqField = $('.skill');
var intMaxValue = parseInt(jqField.attr('rel'), 10);

jqField.jStepper({ minValue: 0, maxValue: intMaxValue });
```

Of course, for this approach to work, you must be sure that the rel attribute is a numeric value.

Notice that I pass 10 as a second parameter to parseInt().
Read why here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp

If you have multiple fields, then the approach above will not work.
In that case something like this is required:

```
$('.skill').each(function() {
    var jqThis = $(this);
    var intMaxValue = parseInt(jqThis.attr('rel'), 10);

    jqThis.jStepper({ minValue: 0, maxValue: intMaxValue });
});
```

Everything above is untested but I hope you get the general idea :)

Comment: Hi @EmKay
Can you please show me how I can remove/change the maxValue attribute.
I tried to recall the jStepper function again like this:
jqThis.jStepper({ minValue: 0}) maxValue didn't work, then jqThis.jStepper({ minValue: 0, maxValue: null}) didn't change, and then jqThis.jStepper({ minValue: 0, maxValue: 999999}) also didn't change.

Can you please help me with this.

Comment: In the current version it is not possible to remove jStepper from an element or change an option later. The plugin is built a long time ago before I knew about the way of setting and getting options that for example jQuery UI uses. But maybe there is some other way your problem can be solved? Maybe you can create the options object dynamically before even starting jStepper on the element..?